# Why do i get this error in Unreal Engine 5 when trying to Package android apps?

Tags: android, game-development, unreal-engine5

Hi guys iv been struggling since yesterday and i have run out of ideas. i build a little android game from a youtube tutorial and when i was done i realised i need android studio to package the game. so i downloaded it and ran it for the first time. i followed Unreal engine documentation to install android studio and make it work with Unreal engine 5. long story short im getting these errors and warnings after setting up everything identical to what they said i should do. i have reinstalled android studios several times. i have version 3.5.3

i have java jdk 18.0.1

here is the full output log in Unreal engine (filtered for Errors and Warnings). Any help would be much appreciated:

```
LogDesktopPlatform: Warning: Unable to read target info for engine
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
PackagingResults: Error: Android Studio is not installed correctly, after attempted installation.
PackagingResults: Error: NDKROOT is not specified; cannot use Android toolchain.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: invalid HTTP response code received. URL: https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream, HTTP code: 0, content length: 0, actual payload size: 0
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: request failed, libcurl error: 56 (Failure when receiving data from the peer)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 0 (Found bundle for host datarouter.ol.epicgames.com: 0x5e2c30d06f0 [can pipeline])
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 1 (Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host datarouter.ol.epicgames.com)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 2 (Connected to datarouter.ol.epicgames.com (34.197.172.226) port 443 (#1))
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 3 (We are completely uploaded and fine)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 4 (OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 5 (Connection died, retrying a fresh connect)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 6 (necessary data rewind wasn't possible)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC315000: libcurl info message cache 7 (Closing connection 1)
LogHttp: Warning: Retry exhausted on https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Class None.Physics'
PackagingResults: Error: Android Studio is not installed correctly, after attempted installation.
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: invalid HTTP response code received. URL: https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream, HTTP code: 0, content length: 0, actual payload size: 0
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: request failed, libcurl error: 6 (Couldn't resolve host name)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: libcurl info message cache 0 (Connection 7 seems to be dead!)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: libcurl info message cache 1 (Closing connection 7)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: libcurl info message cache 2 (Could not resolve host: datarouter.ol.epicgames.com)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E306AB3700: libcurl info message cache 3 (Closing connection 8)
LogHttp: Warning: Retry exhausted on https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
PackagingResults: Error: Android Studio is not installed correctly, after attempted installation.
PackagingResults: Error: NDKROOT is not specified; cannot use Android toolchain.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: invalid HTTP response code received. URL: https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream, HTTP code: 0, content length: 0, actual payload size: 0
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: request failed, libcurl error: 6 (Couldn't resolve host name)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: libcurl info message cache 0 (Connection 10 seems to be dead!)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: libcurl info message cache 1 (Closing connection 10)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: libcurl info message cache 2 (Could not resolve host: datarouter.ol.epicgames.com)
LogHttp: Warning: 000005E2CC751900: libcurl info message cache 3 (Closing connection 11)
LogHttp: Warning: Retry exhausted on https://datarouter.ol.epicgames.com/datarouter/api/v1/public/data?SessionID=%7BD898CB16-4018-BF5C-2D5C-438F294132CD%7D&AppID=UEEditor.Rocket.Release&AppVersion=5.0.1-19764885%2B%2B%2BUE5%2BRelease-5.0&UserID=629adecd4315a96a742d7692dff441d1%7Cf15edf77552b4a8d88ab01f42995fcbc%7Cdc391a24-e4bf-4119-bc10-d176eefc7b1a&AppEnvironment=datacollector-binary&UploadType=eteventstream
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
LogUdpMessaging: Warning: UDP messaging encountered an error. Auto repair routine started for reinitialization
```

[It says this in Unreal engine 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18RRs.png)

[Picture of errors and warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ2Po.png)

[Output Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9qaq.png)

Answer (score 0):

It reads:

> Error: `NDKROOT` is not specified; cannot use Android toolchain.

Which suggest to install the Android NDK and define variable `NDKROOT`.

Please refer to the [manual](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/how-to-set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk-for-your-unreal-engine-development-environment/), which explains how to do that.

Comment: thank you for the help. do i install the android ndk through android studio? and if so what version should i be using?